# Consulta de unión dentro de una función

Tags: php, mysql

Esta función es para el ingreso de usuarios y quiero saber a que tabla pertenece el correo que ingreso por medio del input

```
public function ingresoUsuariosModel($datosModel, $tabla){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT
        u.id_usuario,
        u.id_tipousuario,
        u.correo_usuario,
        u.contrasena_usuario
        FROM
        usuarios AS u
        WHERE
        correo_usuario LIKE '%:correo%'
        UNION
        SELECT
        tc.id_tienda,
        tc.id_tipousuario,
        tc.correo_tienda,
        tc.contrasena_tienda
        FROM
        tiendas_cafe AS tc
        WHERE
        correo_tienda LIKE '%:correo%'");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":correo",$datosModel['correo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> execute();
    return $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt -> close();
}
```

Comment: @Marcos Hols, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho, ya la marque como aceptada, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> quiero saber a que tabla pertenece el correo

Para poder identificar a que tabla pertenece el registro que coincide con el `email` buscando, podrías agregar un [valor personalizado](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) para los registros de cada tabla.

Así por ejemplo:

- Para los registros de la tabla `usuarios` agregamos `'usuario' AS tabla`
- Para los registros de la tabla `tiendas_cafe` agregamos `'tiendas_cafe' AS tabla`

Código:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT
    u.id_usuario,
    u.id_tipousuario,
    u.correo_usuario,
    u.contrasena_usuario,
    'usuario' AS tabla
  FROM usuarios AS u
  WHERE u.correo_usuario LIKE :correo

  UNION

  SELECT
    tc.id_tienda,
    tc.id_tipousuario,
    tc.correo_tienda,
    tc.contrasena_tienda,
    'tiendas_cafe' AS tabla
  FROM tiendas_cafe AS tc
  WHERE tc.correo_tienda LIKE :correo");

$correo = '%'.$datosModel['correo'].'%';
$stmt -> bindParam(":correo", $correo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute();
return $stmt->fetch();
```

**PD**: He modificado la forma en la que estas haciendo la consulta preparada, ya que la aplicada en tu pregunta, no es correcta.

Comment: el correo puede pertenecer a las dos tablas, por eso hago la busqueda en las dos, cambiando mi función con las correcciones que me pasaste, me da error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\backend\models\crud.php:30 

estas es la línea 30
$stmt -> bindParam(":correo",'%'.$datosModel['correo'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @jorgnv, he actualizado mi respuesta. Se me olvido que el valor debe ser una variable

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, como haría para agregar alli una relación a la tabla tipos_usuarios usando el id_tipousuario para obtener el rol que esta en la tabla tipos_usuarios